# PHP Laravel : assistance required as code is not giving proper result

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

The application is built in Laravel. I am trying to insert few more search filter into the existing one. some search filter works and some doesn't. Can you please look into my code and correct me at where i am doing wrong?

This is how my page looks. Previously there were only 2 search fields **Reference** and **keyword**. I have included 4 other search field called **Sector**, **Business Status**, **Turnover** and a **sort by**.
[image]
The **Sector** and **Turnover** search filter are working while **Business status** field and **Sortby** field are not working. And i am out of clue why?

```xml
<form  method="get" action="" class="">
  <label for="cat">
    <p style="margin-top: 6px;">
      <b>Sector</b>
    </p>
  </label>
  <select class="form-control" name="cat" id="cat">
    <option value="" label="Please select">Please select</option>
    <option value="1" label="Technology" <?php if(isset($_GET["cat"]) && $_GET["cat"] == 1){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Technology</option>
    <option value="12" label="Medical" <?php if(isset($_GET["cat"]) && $_GET["cat"] == 12){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Medical</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="business_status" name="business_status" aria-describedby="business_status">
    <option value="" label="Please select">Please select</option>
    <option value="1" label="Live" <?php if(isset($_GET["business_status"]) && $_GET["business_status"] == 1){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Live</option>
    <option value="2" label="Sold" <?php if(isset($_GET["business_status"]) && $_GET["business_status"] == 2){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Sold</option>
    --
  </select>
  <select name="turnover" id="turnover">
    <option value="" label="Please select">Please select</option>
    <option value="1" label="Up to £500k" <?php if(isset($_GET["turnover"]) && $_GET["turnover"] == 1){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Up to £500k</option>
    <option value="2" label="£500k - £1m" <?php if(isset($_GET["turnover"]) && $_GET["turnover"] == 2){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>£500k - £1m</option>
    --     
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="sortby" name="sortby" aria-describedby="sortby" >
    <option value="0" <?php if(isset($_GET["sortby"]) && $_GET["sortby"] == 0){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >Newest To Oldest</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET["sortby"]) && $_GET["sortby"] == 1){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >Oldest To Newest</option>
    --
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and this is the code under app/businesses.php page

```php
public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
{
    if (isset($request->cat)) {
        $query->where('company_category_id', $request->cat);
    }
    if (isset($request->turnover)) {
        $turnoverrange = $request->turnover;
        if ($turnoverrange == 1) {
            $query->where('turnover', '<=', 300000);
        } else if ($turnoverrange == 2) {
            $query->where('turnover', '>=', 300000);
            $query->where('turnover', '<=', 1000000);
        } 
    }         
    if (isset($request->business_status)) {
        $query->where('company_status_id', $request->business_status);
    }      
    if (isset($request->sortby)) {
        $sortbyvalue = $request->sortby;
        if ($sortbyvalue == 0) {
            $query->orderby('updated', 'desc');
        } else if ($sortbyvalue == 1) {
            $query->orderby('updated', 'asc');
        } else if ($sortbyvalue == 2) {
            $query->orderby('turnover', 'asc');
        } else if ($sortbyvalue == 3 ) {
            $query->orderby('turnover', 'desc');
        } 
    }
    return $query;
}
```

The database table is company

[image]

please advise me what I am doing wrong. Specially I dont understand why the sort by feature is not working as it is checking data under same table

Business controller is like this

```
class BusinessesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $myUser = $request->get('myUser');

        SavedSearch::processSavedSearchAction($myUser, $request);

        $page = 1;
        if(isset($_GET["page"])){
            $page = $_GET["page"];
        }

        $businesses = Businesses::Live()->Search($request)->SortBy()->paginate(20)->appends(request()->except(['page','_token']));

        if(is_null($request->input('region')) && is_null($request->input('cat')) && is_null($request->input('date')) && is_null($request->input('turnover')) && is_null($request->input('keyword'))){
            
                    return Redirect::route('businessShow', ['id' => $businesses[0]->company_id]);
          
        }

        $info = View::make('blocks/business-listing-info', [
                'count' => sizeof(Businesses::Live()->Search($request)->get()),
                'page' => $page
            ])->render();



        $dataTagArray = array(
            'businesses' => View::make('blocks/business-listing', [
                'businesses' => $businesses
            ])->render(),
            'business_list_info' => $info,
            'saved_seach_button' => SavedSearch::getSavedSearchForm($myUser, $request)
        );

        $pageData = Page::getPageDataForIdentifier("businessListing", $dataTagArray, $myUser);

        return view('page/show', ['myUser' => $myUser, 'pageData' => $pageData]);
    }
```

Comment: How is the search scope used in your controller?

Comment: @igp - I am not sure how to find that out. I am editing in someone else's code. Can you please suggest

Comment: `I am not sure how to find that out` - it looks like `scopeSearch()` is a method in your model (a "scope"). But when you submit your form, a method in a controller is what handles it, not a scope. Maybe the controller calls that scope, but we can't see if, or how, it does. Where is the controller method that handles the form submission?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - i have updated the question and added code from Businessess.controller.php.  Can you have a look please

Comment: OK well there seems to be one obvious potential issue with sorting, right? This line is where your controller calls your model scope: `$businesses = Businesses::Live()->Search($request) ... ` - but why does that line include `SortBy()` (which means sort by nothing)?  Your scope is already handling sorting?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I assume that sortby() is to display 20 business per page. on the app/businesses.php file there are several areas where business is called like - $businesses = Businesses::Live()->where('company_category_id', '=', $sector)->SortBy()->paginate(20); .

Comment: There is another function on app/businesses.php file public function scopeSortBy($query)
    {   
        if(isset($_GET["sortby"])){ 
            if($_GET["sortby"] == 0){
                return $query->orderby('updated', 'desc');
            } else if($_GET["sortby"] == 1){
                return $query->orderby('updated', 'asc');
            }elseif..
        }
        return $query->where('featured', '=', 0)->orderby('updated', 'desc');
    }

Comment: So sounds like your controller is calling the `SortBy` scope, which is messing up the sorting you already did in the `Search` scope, right?  Some suggestions: 1) A scope called `SortBy` seems like a bad idea, that's a name Laravel already uses; 2) [Scopes are meant to be reusable filters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) that you can call from anywhere. These scopes seem to be tied very specifically to this search form and its inputs, so can't easily be used anywhere else. I'd suggest putting this form-related filtering/ordering code in your controller, not in the scope(s).

Comment: @Don'tPanic can you help me with my latest question please in here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66562070/php-how-to-run-a-line-of-code-after-10-minutes-of-running-another-line-of-code