# PHP - How to Run a line of code after 10 minutes of running another line of code

Tags: php, laravel

I want my application will send a email after 10 minutes of sending another email.

In my application

- A user completes registration with payment
- Application sends the user a payment confirmation email

Now I want to

- send another email 10 minutes After payment confirmation email with welcome tips

Below is the function where for user setup .

```
   public function finishUserSetup($Sub){

    if($Sub == 0){
        $subscription = SubscriptionPlans::where('identifier', '=', "Monthly")->first();
        $expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $subscription->months . ' months'));
        $sub_period = "monthly";
    
    } else{
        $subscription = SubscriptionPlans::where('identifier', '=', "Annually")->first();
        $expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $subscription->months . ' months'));
        $sub_period = "annually";
    }

    $this->expiry_date = $expiry;
    $this->user_type = "SUB";
    $this->subscription_period = $sub_period;
    $this->update();

    $replaceArray = array(
        'fullname' => $this->forename . " " . $this->surname,
        'subscriptionName' => $subscription->name,
        );
    EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("paymentconfirm", $this->email, $this->forename . " " . $this->surname, $replaceArray);

  }
```

In the above function the last line of code is the one  which sends a payment confirmation email to the user which is

```
EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("paymentconfirm", $this->email, $this->forename . " " . $this->surname, $replaceArray);
```

I want to execute the following line of code 10 minutes after the above one

```
EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("WelcomeTips", $this->email, $this->forename . " " . $this->surname, $replaceArray);
```

How to run the above line of code after 10 minutes

Comment: you should using  scheduler 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: it is not something to run on a certain time or regular basis. only after a user completes registration and their payment is conffirmed

Comment: use job and set delay . delay(now()->addMinutes(10)) . https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

Comment: @abofazlrasoli - Can use the delay inside that function .

Comment: Yes , it can ..

Comment: @abofazlrasoli - can you suggest one thing. if there is no time gap required and i want to send the two emails together then what shall i do. shall i just write the two line of code one after another ? like that?   EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("payment");
EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("welcome");

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur  -  can you suggest one thing. if there is no time gap required and i want to send the two emails together then what shall i do. shall i just write the two line of code one after another ? like that? EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("payment"); EmailTemplate::findAndSendTemplate("welcome");

Answer (score 1):

First set up the queue configuration in your laravel project . then create a job with

```
 php artisan make:job YourNameJob
```

Transfer the email sending process into **YoutNameJob** , and finally dispatch **YoutNameJob** twice in the finishUserSetup method, like this

```
 public function finishUserSetup($Sub){

   .
   .
   .

    YoutNameJob::dispatch([arguments])->delay(now());

    YoutNameJob::dispatch([arguments])->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));

  }
```